# Windows store app: Getting whether a radio button is checked and getting the name to be saved in a database

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have this xaml page for a windows store application. I want to get the values and names of the checked radio buttons and then write to a database.

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="RadioButtons.MyRadio"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RadioButtons"
    xmlns:common="using:RadioButtons.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">Sirdots</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Name="MySampleGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Foreground="white" FontSize="40" Height="40">Item 1</TextBlock>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem1" />
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem1"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Foreground="white" FontSize="40" Height="40">Item 2</TextBlock>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem2"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem2"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem2"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Foreground="white" FontSize="40" Height="40">Item 3</TextBlock>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem3"/>
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem3" />
        <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Height="40" GroupName="grpItem3" />

        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"></Button>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is the click event of my button which can only do it for one groupName.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkedValue =
        MySampleGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>()
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsChecked.HasValue && r.IsChecked.Value);

}
```

How can i get the values checked(True or false) and the names of the radio buttons and then write to a database?

Comment: Use LINQ's GroupBy to group them by GroupName, then use a Select on each Grouping to create a Dictionary with a Key that is the GroupName and a Value that is the Selected item in the group (using your FirstOrDefault call).

Comment: Can you show some code samples? Thanks

Comment: Try something like `MySampleGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().GroupBy(radio => radio.GroupName).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault(button => button.IsChecked.HasValue && button.IsChecked.Value));`. This should make an Enumerable of radio buttons. You can then directly use their GroupName to get a value for each one or further process the list via the ToDictionary method.